# Let $f:[-4,\infty)\rightarrow S$ be a continuous function. Then which of the following is/are true?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

Let $f:[-4,\infty)\rightarrow S$ be a continuous function. Then which of the following is/are true?

1. If $S$ is closed, then $f$ has a fixed point.
2. If $S=(-2,\epsilon)$, then $f$ has a fixed point.
3. If For every $\epsilon>0, S=(-4,\epsilon)$, $f$ has a fixed point.
4. If $S=[-1,\infty)$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

I know that $1,4$ are false. To justify this, we can choose $f=x+3$ and $S=[-1,\infty)$. But how to conclude about options $2$ and $3?$

Comment: I think the answer is 3 because there is no reason to exclude $(-4,-2)$.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ in statement $2$?

Comment: The sentence "If $S=(-4,\epsilon)$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, $f$ has a fixed point." is mathematically nonsensical because it is unclear how $\epsilon$ is quantified. Did you mean "for every $\epsilon > 0$: if $S=(-4,\epsilon)$, then $f$ has a fixed point"?

Comment: @5xum, yes, you are saying right. I meant that

Comment: @nitudas Then please edit your question so that users don't have to dig through comments just to figure out what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

2. Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then $g(-4)=f(-4)+4 >-2+4>0$ and $g(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence, by IVP,   there exists $x$ such that $g(x)=0$.

A similar argument works for 3) also.

Comment: Ok @Kavi Rama Murthy. Thanks. So $2,3$ are correct. Right?

Comment: @nitudas Yes, they are both correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks..........

Comment: would you please explain how $3$ is correct. That is here what point have to be chosen

Comment: @nitudas  Use exactly the argument for 2) with  $g(-4)=f(-4)+4 >-2+4>0$ replaced by $g(-4)=f(-4)+4 >-4+4=0$.